# Series convergence for even and odd terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ where
    $a_n = \{\begin{array}{lr}
        1/n, & \text{n is even}\\
       1/n^2, & \text{n is odd}\\
        \end{array}$

Let $S_{e,n}$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum of the series for even terms and $S_{o,n}$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum of the series for odd terms. Prove both of these partial sums converge on (-1,1). Also, usnig the converge of these prove that the parital sums of the original series also converge on (-1,1) and so the series converges on (-1,1).

Trying to review and don't know what to do. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Apply the ratio test (or root test) to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks! So I now see how the ratio test shows convergence of each set of partial sums. To show convergence of all, would I sum both series and then do the ratio test again?

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: To show that the sum converges, use the fact that if two series converge, then their sum converges also.  Alternatively, evaluate $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ to find the interval of convergence directly.